# python importing relative modules

Tags: python, python-import, relative-path, python-module

I have the Python modules a.py and b.py in the same directory.
How can I reliably import b.py from a.py, given that a.py may have been imported from another directory or executed directly? This module will be distributed so I can't hardcode a single path.

I've been playing around with `__file__`, sys.path and os.chdir, but it feels messy. And `__file__` is not always available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Put the directory that contains both in your python path... or vice versa.

Answer (score 6):

Actually, `__file__` is available for an imported module, but only if it was imported from a .py/.pyc file.  It won't be available if the module is built in.  For example:

```
>>> import sys, os
>>> hasattr(os, '__file__')
True
>>> hasattr(sys, '__file__')
False
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the [inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html) module will make the builtin modules more obvious:

```
>>> import os
>>> import sys
>>> inspect.getfile(os)
'/usr/local/lib/python2.6/os.pyc'
>>> inspect.getfile(sys)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.6/inspect.py", line 407, in getfile
    raise TypeError('arg is a built-in module')
TypeError: arg is a built-in module
```